# How to handle errors in getopt

Tags: bash, getopt

Based on tutorials I found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/bash-parse-command-line-arguments) and [here](https://www.shellscript.sh/tips/getopt/index.html) getopt should provide me with information about errors using some combination of characters `:?*`.

But when I used this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

eval set -- "$(getopt -o hspna: --long help,server,project,name-prefix,action: -- "$@")"
while [ : ]; do
  case "$1" in
    -s | --server)
      echo "Setting server"
      shift
      ;;
    -p | --project)
      echo "Setting project"
      shift
      ;;
    -n | --name-prefix)
      echo "Setting name prefix"
      shift
      ;;
    -a | --action)
      echo "Setting action"
      shift
      ;;
    --)
      shift
      break
      ;;
    -h | --help)
      echo "Providing help 1"
      exit
      ;;
    :)
      echo "Providing help 2"
      exit
      ;;
    ?)
      echo "Providing help 3"
      exit
      ;;
    *)
      echo "Providing help 4"
      exit
      ;;
  esac
done

echo $@
echo "Configured"
exit
```

Then following command that was supposed to show an error gave me the following output:

```
$ ./debug.sh -a -s -b -- foo bar baz
getopt: invalid option -- 'b'
Setting action
Setting server
foo bar baz
Configured
```

I was expecting that:

1. `Providing help 2` will appear due to `-a` missing a value
2. `Providing help 3` will appear due to `-b` not being a valid parameter
3. `Providing help 4` will appear due to overall errors
4. `Configured` should never appear since the previous 3 points have an exit

But none of the above was true.

Also when testing further even more things did not work as expected.

```
# Expecting error due to missing value for `-a` but instead everything worked fine
$ ./debug.sh -a -s
Setting action
Setting server

Configured
```

```
# This time I expected everything to work fine, since I provided `X` as value of `-a`, but error was shown.
$ ./debug.sh -aX
Setting action
Providing help 3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

Util-linux `getopt` prints and handles errors.

```
if ! args="$(getopt \
     -n your_command \
     -o hspna: \
     --long help,server,project,name-prefix,action: \
     -- "$@"\
)"; then
   exit 1
fi
eval "set -- $args"
...
```

```
$ ./util -a
your_command: option requires an argument -- 'a'
```

> I was expecting that:

I do not understand why. There is no such documentation in `getopt`. No, `getopt` will not output `?` nor `:`.  You can handle *your* (as the author of the program) errors, like you forgot to handle the option in `case` that you have given to `getopt` - you handle that with `*)`.

The `?` is a glob that matches any character. Because *you* forgot a `shift` after `esac` before `done`, `X` remains in `$1`, which is one character and is matched by `?)`. You meant `'?')`. This should go into `*)` case, and you should print yourself an error message.

Example, subjective in my style that I use (many people do not like `set -eu`):

```
set -euo pipefail
args=$(getopt -o ab -- "$@")
eval "set -- $args"
aflag=0
while (($#)); do
   case "$1" in
   -a) afloag=1; ;;
   --) shift; break;
   *) echo "Och no, I forgot about -b, or some other error!" >&2; exit 1; ;;
   easc
   shift
done
```

Comment: `:` and `?` was mentioned in the first tutorial I linked in point `2.3. Error Reporting in getopts`.

Comment: `getopts` is not `getopt`. Yes, the super standard `getopts` that comes builtin with your shell reports errors with `:` and `?`. An external program completely unrelated to shell done by util-linux group called `getopt` does not use `:` nor `?`.